# Submiting data via AJAX to url with $_REQUEST

Tags: php, ajax

I've got an issue with posting data to url like below.
Only thing I get is error 500 in browser's console.

BUT if I remove *?mod=printing&sub=personal* from the url it works fine.

```
 $('.printDocument').click( function () { 

    var userID = $(this).closest('tr').find(".userid").text(); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "/index.php?mod=printing&sub=personal",
            data: {userID : userID},
            success: function(data){
                var win = window.open();
                win.document.write(data);
            }
        })  

    })
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The issues seems to lie in PHP file.

Comment: When you have a server error 500, then you check the server logs: /var/log/apache2/access.log OR /var/log/nginx/access.log (dependable on what you are using) and if you use some sort of *AMP software then google where are the logs for it.

Comment: @UmairKhan when I open this file like regular URL i mean *url: "/modules/printing/personal.php" * it works fine

Comment: @idzczakp Try opening file as with GET params like *url: "/index.php?mod=printing&sub=personal"*. `500` error code is server provided. So there must be issue in PHP coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a failure clause and check the console or use a breakpoint, may contain some hints:

```
fail: (function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    console.log(error.message)
    console.log(error.stack)
}
```

But as Umair suggested, issue relies on the server side.

On a side note from [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) site:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

If you are using latest jQuery, you should write it like so:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: '/index.php?mod=printing&sub=personal',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {userID : userID},
  dataType: 'html'
});

request.done(function( data ) {
  var win = window.open();
  win.document.write(data);
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, error ) {
  console.log(error.message)
  console.log(error.stack)
});
```

Tested with jQuery v3.5.0